# Send Host header when accessing IP address in Firefox

Tags: firefox, testing, http-headers

This isn't really a programming question but more about programming and testing tools.

Is there a way to get Firefox to send the header

```
Host: mydomain.com
```

when accessing a page at

```
http://ip.address.goes.here/
```

so that Apache can route it to the correct VirtualHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use the [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) extension to manually add it each time.

Comment: The new extension that works: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value

Answer (score 8):

You can add the host name and ip-address to your hosts file.

Comment: NOTE: This is one of the few situations where editing your hosts file is justifiable. (Many times people edit their host files, it is a bad idea).

Comment: Sometimes you have more than one machine you want to access with the same Host header (dev,test,prod). In such cases, hosts file editing is not really an option.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [Modify Headers Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to modify the "Host" header successfully for me. Doing `curl site.com -H 'Host: new-host'` works, though.

Comment: That extension URL is 404ing.

Comment: Extension no longer there, but [simple-modify-headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-modify-header/) worked for me after some fiddling.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a site and wish to map the host header to an IP (perhaps your local dev box) for testing purposes, then you should consider [editing the hosts file instead.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file)

Answer (score 1):

Just setup an  entry in the hosts file. Always worked for me  :)

Comment: this doesn't work if you want to translate one IP to a different IP (eg for doing remote admin over SSH tunnel of devices that require a correct IP address in the host header)